# Bose Hubbard Model Phase Transitions

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, phase-transition, bose-hubbard-model

I am studying the Bose Hubbard model by reading this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/9712307.pdf). I have three questions:

(1) The sides of the Mott lobes are symmetry-breaking phase transitions (second order). What is the corresponding order parameter? Why is this the order parameter?

(2) All phase transitions for this model are quantum phase transitions and occur due to quantum fluctuations. Quantum fluctuations are due to an uncertainty principle, which is due to noncommutting Hermitian operators. What are the noncommutting Hermitian operators that cause the quantum fluctuations in this model?

(3) Consider the points on the vertical $\mu$ axis of the phase diagram that connects one Mott lobe to the next (i.e. $t = 0, \mu = 1, 2, 3, ...$). What type of phase transition (1st order, 2nd order) occurs when the system travels from one Mott insulator to another on the vertical $\mu$ axis when the hopping constant $t$ is set to 0.

Comment: Regarding the first point, the order parameter is $\langle b_i \rangle$, i.e. the expectation value of the bosonic annihilation operator. You can also use the creation operator if you prefer. This is non vanishing in the superfluid phase where there is a spontaneous symmetry breaking, while it is zero in the Mott phase, where instead the ground state is symmetric

Comment: @Matteo Thank you very much for (1).